# Parsing String to Date with SimpleDateFormat, nb of milliseconds varying

Tags: java, parsing, date, timestamp, simpledateformat

I have such a date in a String from a text file: `String string = 2014-10-03 00:58:59.765`
So I parse it that way:

```
Date timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .parse(string);
```

However some of the timestamps have less than 3 digits on the milliseconds, and I get a ParseException trying to use the same SimpleDateFormat on them. edit: it happens when the milliseconds are 000. example: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-10-03 00:59:49"`

This is my work around:

```
if (string.length() == 23) {
                    timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                            .parse(string);
                } else if (string.length() == 22) {
                    timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS")
                            .parse(string);
                } else if string.length() == 21) {
                    timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS")
                            .parse(string);
                } else if (string.length() == 19) {
                    timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                            .parse(string);
                }
```

Isn't there a better way to do that?

Comment: 2014-10-03 00:58:59.7, 2014-10-03 00:58:59.71, 2014-10-03 00:58:59.716 should work with yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS. Can you paste your string with which you got parse exception?

Comment: Yes, it is in the case milliseconds are 000: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-10-03 00:59:49"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decide by the help of `.` in String which contains `SSS` and note it's not always safe,so be careful,as for `SSS` it can parse `.767`,`.76`,`.7` of *milliseconds*.

```
    Date timestamp = null;

    if(string.contains(".")) {
        timestamp =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        .parse(string);
    } else {
        timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        .parse(string);
    }

    System.out.println(timestamp);
```

Note here if you parse *milisecond* `.76` with `.SSS` than during retrieval you have to format it with `.SS` otherwise it returns `.076` instead of `.76` same thing happens with other. So, be careful!